# How to solve a RAW stream playback problem with GStreamer and VAAPi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, gstreamer, vaapi

I am currently experiencing a small problem with GStreamer, here are more details:

Configuration:

- Intel i7-6700
- Intel HD Graphics 530
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- GStreamer1.0
- VAAPI plugin

I receive a `UDP` stream from a video source, this stream is sent in `RAW` `UYVY` format. Here is my command line to decode it:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port="1234" caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:2, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1920, height=(string)1080, colorimetry=(string)BT709-2, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1188110121, timestamp-offset=(uint)4137478200, seqnum-offset=(uint)7257, a-framerate=(string)25" ! rtpvrawdepay ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`

Problem as we can see on the screenshot below, the `CPU` load (right) is far too high for this kind of task and we can see the `GPU` load (left) which is almost zero.

[image: CPU & GPU charge]

To overcome this problem, I want to use the VAAPI graphics acceleration as I did in a previous project with `H264` of which here is the command line below:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=1234 caps= "application/x-rtp, media\=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, profile-level-id=(string)640028, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2665415388, timestamp-offset=(uint)3571350145, seqnum-offset=(uint)18095, a-framerate=(string)25" ! rtph264depay ! queue !  vaapih264dec low-latency=1 ! autovideosink`

The line above works perfectly and the `CPU` has almost no more loads. So I adapt this command line to use it with a `RAW` stream, here is the command:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port="1234" caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:2, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1920, height=(string)1080, colorimetry=(string)BT709-2, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1188110121, timestamp-offset=(uint)4137478200, seqnum-offset=(uint)7257, a-framerate=(string)25" ! rtpvrawdepay ! vaapidecodebin ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`

It is the same line as the one at the beginning but I changed the element `decodebin` by `vaapidecodebin` as I had replaced `avdec_h264` by `vaapih264dec` for my `H264` stream. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I end up with this error:

`WARNING: wrong pipeline: unable to connect rtpvrawdepay0 to vaapidecodebin0`

How I can solve this problem? Do you have any leads to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to accelerate here? The CPU load is probably either due to the `videoconvert` as this is run in software to convert UYVY into a format your renderer supports (Hopefully that's another YUV format and not RGB) or it is the data transfer of the uncompressed data from CPU memory to GPU memory.

Note that transferring uncompressed image data is a *much* higher data rate than compressed H.264 video.

If you think the `videoconvert` is the expensive part you may want to try to use OpenGL for convert and displaying: `.. ! glupload ! glcolorconvert ! glimagesink`.

Maybe `vaapipostproc` can help you with color conversion if you don't want to go the OpenGL route.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried the command line by replacing videoconvert by OpenGL that improves the result a little but a core of the CPU remains loaded at around 40% while the 3 others are around 6-7%. I would like all cores have approximately the same charge so that it is homogeneous.

Comment: Okay no worries, and the vaapidecodebin setting doesn't work in this kind of situation?

Comment: You are dealing with raw image data - what is VAAPI supposed to "decode" here?

Comment: I found another solution to harmonize my CPU using the taskset command. Now I have three cores that are loaded at almost the same level.